# What CSS code can I use to style this how I want?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: What I want to be done]
[Quick Image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gc9B.png)

How can I move this text box up and put information in the circled area in CSS? I am more of the developer type rather than a designer, so I need help with this. The text area should be exactly the same.
Thanks! 

EDIT: As for the rest of the form, I want it to be centered in the second half of the screen. Hopefully I clarified.

Comment: Can you give us an initial code of what you want to do, and the issues you are getting?

Comment: `#mymaindiv textarea {
 padding-left: 3px;
}
#a-div-inside-the-other-one {
 margin-left: 60px;
} 
#mymaindiv form input[name="argument"] {
 font-size: 50px;
 padding: 3px;
}
#mymaindiv textarea {  
  width: 49%;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
`

Comment: The textarea is inside two divs

Comment: I just want the text area to take up half of the page and the rest of the form to take up the other half, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
<div style="float:left;width:200px;height:200px">
    <textarea style="width:100%;height:100%"></textarea>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:200px;height:200px">
    <div>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        Circled Area
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use div `float:left` property for that

**DEMO:**

```css
div.main{
float:left;
}
.txt{
  height:600px;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input type="textarea" class="txt">
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div>
  <input type="text" class="txt2"></div>
  
  <div>
  <input type="text" class="txt2"></div>
</div>
```

**other method**

you can use `<br>` tag
**DEMO**

```css
div.main{
float:left;
}
.txt{
  height:600px;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input type="textarea" class="txt">
</div>
<div class="main">
  
  <input type="text" class="txt2">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="txt2">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="txt2">
</div>
```

Comment: When I do this, what I want to be next to the text area ends up below it.

Comment: both elements total width should be below 100%

Answer (score 0):

Float the text area to the left and put a div around the circled content and float it right. The text box will rise to the top in the middle.

Comment: I want the rest of the information next to the text area, but this makes it over to the right. I want the text area to take up half of the screen, and the form to be on the other half. Maybe centered on the other half of the screen if you will.

Comment: @Hal Noyes - Please put a bit more effort in your answers, [here's how to write a good one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)